# Customize org-mode state change logging text

Tags: org-mode

How can I edit the format of the `org-mode` state change logging text? Specifically I'd like to be able to log with a timestamp excluding the time like

```
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-05-14 Tue]
```

It currently writes something like

```
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-05-14 Tue 12:00]
```